# Reports and Custom Searches

Tags: custom-reports, advanced-search

We currently have circa 1000 community groups across the UK and need to run a report on the amount held in each region or county.

I can obtain the numbers by running individual advanced searches for each region by setting the criteria etc, but is there a simple & effective way but building a report around this information?

Many thanks

Terry

Answer (score 1):

There is an extension called [Report Plus](https://civicrm.org/extensions/reportplus) which provides nice matrix on Contact, Contribution Membership etc. I guess you can use this extension to build your report.

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation Pradeep. Is there any suitable options built into Civi naively rather than via an extension? We would need to pay our support company to add an extension unfortunately and I am keen to keep our costs down. Thanks again, Terry